# Boot Windows 10 ISO from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows, iso

I want to install Windows 10 because I want to play some games and on Ubuntu is not that playable so I downloaded a iso file from Microsoft page and now I don't know how to install! I mounted the iso file and ran Setup.exe but it says

> Windows installation cannot be started from the current operating
>   system. To install Windows, boot from the installation media, or
>   upgrade from a supported operating system and restart the
>   installation.

Is there any other way to boot Windows 10 iso from Ubuntu?

Comment: The best way to boot a Windows ISO is to use Universal USB Installer and dump it on a USB Stick. What you are trying to do will shoot yourself in the foot, because when you reboot, you won't have access to that ISO file anymore.

Comment: On a different note, have you looked at [Wine](http://winehq.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- Burn a boot DVD disk. Make sure to 'burn an iso file'. (Do *not* create a data DVD with the iso file.)
- Create a boot USB drive. You can use mkusb-nox or mkusb-dus alias mkusb version 12. See these links,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7#Making_a_USB_drive_to_install_Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7#Making_a_USB_drive_to_install_Windows)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/12](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/12)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation)

Comment: Thanks! But i need without DVD or USB! But thanks!

Comment: You need a medium (some kind of drive), where you install from. It is possible, but much more difficult to install via the network from another computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Windows without removing Ubuntu, you could download `Virtual Box` and you can run Windows inside Ubuntu, but the gaming performance may not be good as real metal.

Comment: Thanks! That's good! but i want to replace Ubuntu!

Comment: Then you can can make a bootable DVD or USB, and then boot from it. It is the way of installing any operating system

Comment: Yeah your right! I can do that but i can't use a USB because i don't have enough space and i don't have a empty DVD! But thanks for the suggestion!